# Changing columns do not reflect at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, columndefinition

I am having an issue when I change my `ColumnDefinitions` at runtime. When I do, the columns `Width` does ***not reflect immediately***. If I resize the current window/usercontrol then the `Width` does reflect.

I am following `MVVM` as well, I have a `DependencyProperty` that allows me to change them as needed on the `Grid`.

Currently here is what I am using and does work if I resize the window and or control the `Grid` is on...

```
public static void ColumnSpacerChanged(
            DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(obj is Grid) || ((Grid)obj).ColumnDefinitions.Count == 0 || (int)e.NewValue == (int)e.OldValue)
                return;

            Grid grid = (Grid)obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; i++)
            {
                if(grid.ColumnDefinitions[i].Tag != null && grid.ColumnDefinitions[i].Tag.ToString() == COLUMN_SPACER)
                {
                    grid.ColumnDefinitions[i] = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength((int)e.NewValue, GridUnitType.Pixel), Tag = COLUMN_SPACER };
                }
            }

            grid.UpdateLayout(); // Tried this, but doesn't work

        }
```

> I have tried the following and none work.

```
 grid.UpdateLayout();
 grid.Refresh; // (off the parent)
```

Is there something I am missing when I change the `ColumnDefinitions` during run-time they immediately do not reflect?

Comment: Try calling `grid.InvalidateMeasure()` and _then_ `grid.UpdateLayout()`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel thanks for the kind comments. Neither worked, still no update, but your comment's lead me to find another method that does work. It is `InvalidateArrange`,  it Invalidates the arrange state (layout) for the element. After the invalidation, the element will have its layout updated which works perfect!

Comment: I should have guessed, since (upon inspecting the code) it turns out that modifying `ColumnDefinitions` or `ColumnDefinition.Width` should automatically call `InvalidateMeasure` on the parent grid.

Comment: @MikeStrobel yes you are  correct, `InvalidateMeasure` is called already when modifying `ColumnDefinitions`. First time I have ever came across something like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with some help from @Mike Strobel....

```
InvalidateArrange()
```

This needs to be called to invalidate the arrange state (layout) for the element. After this invalidation the element will then have its layout updated and reflected asynchronously.